# Apex Http Request Class

Tags: android, salesforce, apex

I was trying to use salesforce apex classes.
According to documentation we need to use System namespace,
I am not sure how to use it with this,

I want to use httprequest class of apex.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for making Http Request :

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
//Set end point url here
req.setEndpoint('www.sampleurl.com');
//set method of your request
req.setMethod('GET'); 

Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse response = h.send(req);
```

You can search for HttpRequest and HttpResponse classes for more methods you can use in this request according to your requirment.

Comment: thanks but i was not able to figure out how to get this httpRequest class of apex.The httprequest class defined in apache does not have this methods.We have to use apex defined classes.

Comment: May i know what is your requirement, and why you want to use apex class in apache ?

Comment: I want to use http classes of apex.How to include this ?

Comment: Why you precisely want to use HttpRequest of Apex, If you want to make some http call you can use apache library's class for the same.
If your requirement is to fetch some data from salesforce org you can create Rest Service.

Comment: Actually i want to make an request to apex but i dont know how to  use this httprequest's endpoint method.How can i use httpRequest class you have answered in the asked question?

Comment: Until you don't tell me what the exact thing you want to implement I can't help you in this, as I already mentioned is that, making call from any way is the same, using apache Httprequest or apex HttpRequest, but the point is that you can only use apex standard classes only withing apex code.

Comment: I want to make apex request call of salesforce through my android app having the endpoint url and also i have the post body keyvalue pairs.I want to save a file as pdf which is already save there on database.